# Insertion of data into multiple table using primary key and foreign key through html form with php procedual and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, multiple-tables

I am new to complicated databases. I want to add supplier detail I the database, which has 3 tables with name product,  supplier, and purchase invoice.

product have an id(primary key), product_name, and supplier_name(foreign key)

A supplier have a supplier_name and supplier_detail

and purchase invoice have reference_no#(primary key) product_id(foreign key) product_price product_quantity amount_paid and purchase_date

I want to add detail in database using php form but how could I? I am confusing with multiple table and foreign key.

Need suggestion as well as answer with source code? And also I want to know is database I have created is correct or not?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We don't write code on demand here. If you can give your problem a go, we can help if you get stuck. Do you have your tables created in a MySQL database? If so, write a PHP-based form that inserts into just one table to start with. If you need a hand, there are lots of tutorials to help you do that.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly would recommend you start reading first about relations in databases.

[This would help you a lot](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561).

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpfull to me.